# Error in parsing json with class Kotlin Android

Tags: android, json, kotlin

hi i am trying to parse JSON with kotlin

below is my json code

```
    [{
    "module":"1",
    "books":[{"name":"bookname1","authors":"author1, author 2"},
             {"name":"bookname2","authors":"author1, author 2"},
             {"name":"bookname3","authors":"author1, author 2"}]
},
{
    "module":"2",
    "books":[{"name":"bookname1","authors":"author1, author 2"},
             {"name":"bookname2","authors":"author1, author 2"},
             {"name":"bookname3","authors":"author1, author 2"}]
},
{
    "module":"3",
    "books":[{"name":"bookname1","authors":"author1, author 2"},
             {"name":"bookname2","authors":"author1, author 2"},
             {"name":"bookname3","authors":"author1, author 2"}]
},
{
    "module":"4",
    "books":[{"name":"bookname1","authors":"author1, author 2"},
             {"name":"bookname2","authors":"author1, author 2"},
             {"name":"bookname3","authors":"author1, author 2"}]
},
{
    "module":"5",
    "books":[{"name":"bookname1","authors":"author1, author 2"},
             {"name":"bookname2","authors":"author1, author 2"},
             {"name":"bookname3","authors":"author1, author 2"}]
}]
```

please note that this json response starts with array

here is my class to parse it

```
class SemdetailsPArser {

    @SerializedName("module")
    @Expose
    var module: String? = null
    @SerializedName("books")
    @Expose
    var books: List<Book>? = null




}

class Book {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    var name: String? = null
    @SerializedName("authors")
    @Expose
    var authors: String? = null

}
```

And here is my code

`//interface`

```
interface SemdetailsFetcher {
    @GET("test/json/sub1.json")
    fun getCurrentSemData(): Call<SemdetailsPArser>
}
```

here is my code in activity

```
fun getCurrentData() {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
        val service = retrofit.create(SemdetailsFetcher::class.java)
        val call = service.getCurrentSemData()
        call.enqueue(object : Callback, retrofit2.Callback<SemdetailsPArser> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: retrofit2.Call<SemdetailsPArser>?,
                response: retrofit2.Response<SemdetailsPArser>?
            ) {
               // val thisthig = response?.body();
                println("here 1 ${response?.body().toString()}")
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
                println("here 2")
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: retrofit2.Call<SemdetailsPArser>?, t: Throwable?) {
                println("here 3 $t")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {

                    println("secodn success")
                    val sampleResp = response.body()!!

                    println(sampleResp)
                }
            }


        })
    }
```

and i am getting this error

```
here 3 com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
```

I understood that this might be related to my parsing class

here i am getting an array of json info, i tried the same code with another json

```
{
    "person": {
        "name": "Don",
        "age": 35
    },
    "books": [{
            "id": 800,
            "name": "book 1",
            "description": "clear sky",
            "icon": "01n"
        },
        {
            "id": 801,
            "name": "book 2",
            "description": "clear sky 1",
            "icon": "01N"
        }
    ],

    "city": "bgvnslsl",
    "id": 1851632,
    "bname": "abcd",
    "code": 200
}
```

this was working perfectly when i changed the parsing class and interface

My problem is that i dont know how to write a class to parse a json response starting with an array

Comment: your parsing will not work as your response is json array and the code you have written expects a json object response

Comment: yes exactly, i understood that, can you shed some light on how to achieve that?i tried the online gson generator, the above class is generated with that same json input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting list of `SemdetailsPArser` , so you should define return type as List of `SemdetailsPArser`

This should fix problem.

```
interface SemdetailsFetcher {
    @GET("test/json/sub1.json")
    fun getCurrentSemData(): Call<List<SemdetailsPArser>>
}
```

You also need to change it in other parts of code.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting means that you're trying to parse JSON array, thinking it should be JSON object. JSON array is the thing between these `[]`, while JSON object is in curly brackets like these `{}`. So your first JSON corresponds to something like `List<Module>`, it's not an object, but a list of them. Each module has a list of books in it.

So all said, it should be like this

```
interface SemdetailsFetcher {
    @GET("test/json/sub1.json")
    fun getCurrentSemData(): Call<List<SemdetailsPArser>>
}
```

By the way, if you define your POJOs right, you won't need all the annotations.

Comment: thank you, the way i called the class was wrong, so careless of me, cost me a day

Answer (score 0):

Create SemdetailsPArser class

`data class SemdetailsPArser(
    val books: List<Book>,
    val module: String
)`

Next create  Book class

```
data class Book(
val authors: String,
val name: String
```

)

next in the interface (SemdetailsFetcher)

```
interface SemdetailsFetcher {
@GET("test/json/sub1.json")
fun getCurrentSemData(): Call<List<SemdetailsPArser>>
```

}